# How do I manuever this element on my website

Tags: html, css

The current code I have is

```
<div class ="main">
<div id="post" class="post">
                <div class = "upvote_downvote">
                    <div id = "upvote" class = "upvote">
                        <div class="upvote_arrow_tip"></div>

                    </div>
                    <div class = "score">
                        <p>1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "downvote">
                        <div class="downvote_arrow_tip"></div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "content">
                    <a class = "name_and_date">
                        <spam class="name">
                            <img class = "pfp" width = "30" height = "30" src="" alt="pfp">
                            <h3 class="first_last_name">FIRST NAME LAST NAME</h3>
                            <p class = "username">@USERNAME</p>
                        </spam>
                        <i class="date_time">DATE &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp TIME</i>
                    </a>
                    <p class = "contents">POST CONTENTS</p>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

It is coming out like this:
[image: output]

What I want to happen is the `upvote_downvote` div to be to the left of the `content` div. However, when I applied `float: left` to both divs, the following occured:
[image: output]

The `name_and_date` container is a flex box, does this cause issues?
And, the border is being applied to the `post` div.

Comment: There are quite a lot HTML syntax issues, e.g. do you mean `&nbsp;`? You should not use non-breaking spaces to format your layout; use CSS instead. Also, please post your CSS in your question, and make a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use `display: inline-block` for the container.